# Постановка запросов к серверу в очередь

Tags: spring, spring-boot

Подскажите пожалуйста логику выполнения такого условия.
Я написал простой сервис для вывода данных о погоде по api.

Клиент вводит данные, например название города, и получает страницу с набором погодных данных.

Однако я хочу, чтобы приложение обрабатывало только **один** запрос за раз. Т.е. если зашло миллион пользователей и несколько из них одновременно выполнили поиск, их запросы становятся в очередь и выполняются друг за другом.

Моя программа выполнена на spring boot, возможно есть библиотека или настройка чтобы реализовать этот функционал. И если нет то покажите направление как можно реализовать такое условие.

Спасибо.

Comment: Уточните пожалуйста, зачем вам нужен такой подход: может быть, вы таким образом хотите решить проблемы с синхронизацией или у вас только одно ядро и вы пытаетесь увеличить производительность.

Comment: первый вариант с синхронизацией это 100%. но по поводу увеличения производительности тоже стоит задача.

Answer (score 0):

Озвученный вами вопрос решается в Spring Boot из коробки настройкой количества потоков обработчиков запросов в конфигурационном файле. Если вы используете Tomcat, то

```
server.tomcat.max-threads: 1
```

Если Jetty, то

```
server.jetty.acceptors: 1
```

Если Undertow, то

```
server.undertow.worker-threads: 1
```

[Документация](https://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/current/reference/html/common-application-properties.html)

Но нужно ли это делать? Ваш вопрос очень похож на [проблему XY](https://ru.meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/709/%D0%A7%D1%82%D0%BE-%D1%82%D0%B0%D0%BA%D0%BE%D0%B5-%D0%9E%D1%88%D0%B8%D0%B1%D0%BA%D0%B0-%D0%BC%D0%BE%D0%BB%D0%BE%D1%82%D0%BA%D0%B0-%D0%B8%D0%BB%D0%B8-%D0%9E%D1%88%D0%B8%D0%B1%D0%BA%D0%B0-xy). Если вы опишите роблему, которую пытаетесь решить таким способом (лучше в отдельном вопросе), возможно, вам дадут более релевантные рекоммендации.